# Opto-Isolater always on by higher voltage

Tags: arduino, opto-isolator

I use an AQH3213 Opto-Isolater. When I use 3.3V on the 'dc motor side', everything works fine and it 'turns off and on in an interval of 1 second'. But when I use 5V, it's always on....

Do you have any suggestions what I do wrong?

The simple test code is correct, because it works with 3.3V; so must be a curcuit problem I guess.

[image: Curcuit]

Comment: You have supplied what appears to be a Fritzing wiring diagram. We prefer *schematic* diagrams so we understand the schema, the part numbers and the pin functions. See if you can generate the schematic and upload that instead. Add links to datasheets for components used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AQH3213](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0e1f/0900766b80e1fa51.pdf) is an optically isolated **triac** device for controlling **AC** loads. It should not be used on **DC** loads because the triac, once properly "fired" will remain on all the time until power is removed.

The reason it "appears" to work correctly at the lower DC voltage is that the triac *will* act as an on-off device if the current taken by load is below the threshold-latching level. Once above the threshold level it will remain permanently activated unless power is removed or cycled (as when used in an AC application).

Comment: Ah thank you very much! Do you have an alternative for me for DC? Can't find fitting ICs adhoc...

Comment: Try looking for an optically driven MOSFET - I believe panasonic also make those and these have pretty low impedances and are more suitable. Else, decide that a regular opto driving a regular N channel MOSFET is a good ploy. Else, do you really need an optical isolation in your circuit.